# Navigating between fragment bug (BottomNavigationView Visibility)

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

I'm trying to make the `BottomNavigationView` **invisible** in fragment A, but **visible** on switching to fragment B, i tried logging their lifecycle throughout the navigation and tried setting the `visiblity` accordingly but still to no avail...

I'm using the `Navigation` to navigate between the fragments, the navigations are done in the fragments `adapter` passing the `onClick` view

**Edit :** I tried using `onDestinationListener`

**The Bug:** It works randomly

**FragmentA:**

```
lateinit var bvn: BottomNavigationView

val TAG = "TAG"


override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_post_detail, container, false)

    Log.d(TAG, "PDF: onCreateView")
val navController = findNavController(requireActivity(),R.id.nav_host_fragment) 
      navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
        if(destination.id == R.id.postDetailFragment) {
            bnv.visibility = View.GONE
        } else {
            bnv.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }

    ...
    ...


    return view
}
```

**FragmentB:**

```
lateinit var bvn: BottomNavigationView

val TAG = "TAG"

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false)


    Log.d(TAG, "Profile: onCreateView")

   val navController = Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
        if(destination.id == R.id.nav_profile) {
            bnv.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            Log.d(TAG, "Profile: bnv visible")
        }
    }
   ...
   ...

    return view
}
```

**FragmentA adapter:**

```
  ...
  ...
  override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Viewholder, position: Int) {

        // navigating to FragmentB...

        holder.imageProfile.setOnClickListener {
            val action = PostDetailFragmentDirections
                .actionPostDetailFragmentToNavProfile(comment.publisher)
            it.findNavController().navigate(action)
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please attach code when you switch from A to B, I mean fragment transaction you setup

Comment: done,,,pls check

Comment: could you try override onHiddenChanged in FragmentB? I think FragmentB should trigger it, because you using navigation component so I'm not sure about that. Additional easy way is adapter should callback again FragmentA when imageProfile click, and you only set visibility on it, no need check full lifecycle

Comment: That's not how you should hide and show your `BottomNavigationView`, you should be [follow the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#listen_for_navigation_events) and use an `OnDestinationChangedListener`.

Comment: the bug still persist...

Comment: help needed here https://stackoverflow.com/q/61646296/7795072