# BottomNavView remains hidden onNavigation between Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-architecture-components, bottomnavigationview

Prior to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61604091/7795072), i implemented the `HideBottomViewOnScrollBehaviour` to the `BottomNavVew`, and `onDestinationChangedListener`in each `fragment` to control the visiblity of the `BottomNavView`

**Bug :** when i scroll-down and the `BottomNavView` collapse/hide in `FragmentA` and i try navigating to the `FragmentB`, the `BottomNavView` remains hidden, but if i scroll-up justt for the `BNV` to re-appear and try switching to the same fragment, the `BNV` becomes visible,

can anyone help with an explanation...?

Answer (score 1):

because when you navigate from A to B. The listener in Fragment A will be destroyed with Fragment A. And Fragment B will not receive and destination change because there is no change yet. As you init it again in Fragment B so it doesn't know you come from A.

Just put the onDestinationChangedListener with visibility logic in Activity.

Comment: did that, implemented the visiblity logic on the parent activity, and even in each fragment... still same problem

Comment: you should remove those listener in each fragment, because those will override what you did in parent activity